# Adding multiple ranges to an array then using .value to copy/paste to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have several named ranges (timelinemarket, clientdetailsmarket, premisesmonthlymarket, cashinflowmarket, cashoutflowmarket) that I am looping through one by one and using .value to transfer to a new sheet.  This requires a big chunk of code as I am looping through each individually and doing the .value action.  All of the ranges are (or are made to be) the same height (72 rows, currently).

What I want is to add all of the values in the ranges to a single array which would look something like:

| range 1 col 1 | range 1 col 2 | range 2 col 1 | range 3 col 1 | range 4 col 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value | value |

Then I want to just take that array and paste it into the new worksheet at location x.

My understanding is that I could loop through the ranges one by one, add the values to the array, then use something like the below to put them into the new worksheet:

```
range("newrange") = myarray
```

The ranges to be processed will all be the same height, 72 rows, but they have different numbers of columns.

1. Range 1: 72 rows x 2 columns
2. Range 2: 72 rows x 1 column
3. Range 3: 72 rows x 1 column
4. Range 4: 72 rows x 1 column

Resulting Array: 72 rows x 5 columns

Comment: Do you understand what an array is, no offence? Please, edit your question and try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing. Trying to understand your code looks difficult enough.

Comment: Sort of.. I have read multiple tutorials and I think I get it but then I try to actually use them and it doesn't behave in the way I'm expecting.  I have edited my question to HOPEFULLY be clearer...

Comment: You shouldn't delete all your code. Maybe somebody else more patient will better understand its meaning... Now, in order to give some more relevance, I think you should show us how your data to be processed looks. I know to handle arrays in a lot of ways and I like helping, but without seeing the input it is practically impossible to show you how such an output should be created...

Comment: I think you were right, the code doesn't actually add anything to the question.  All I need to know is how to add the ranges' values to the array... and if that is in fact a good method of achieving my desired result!  And thank you for taking the time to answer, really appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is to use the range `Value` property. For instance `arr = Range("A1:B4").value` puts the range in an array having two columns and four rows.  Is it a little clearer? You may test it. Then, use 'Debug.Print arr(2, 2)`. It will return the former range "B2" value...

Comment: If you have a named ("myR") range for "B2:D4", you can simple put it in an array writing `Dim arr` `arr = Range("myR").Value`. Then, 'MsgBox arr(3, 3)` will return the value of "D4"... You can also slice/extract rows from the array, but not like you supposed in your initial question... an array does not have a `Row` property...

Comment: You can add array values by iteration, but this way consumes Excel resources for nothing, since is easier to create it at once. You can build a processed array by iteration, like a result of some other arrays/ranges processing. Now you show the input, but how to connect the input to the desired output? What algorithm to be applied in order to do that? Before being a (good) programmer, you must learn asking questions. It have to present a **reproductible** situation. In which terms are you waiting for an answer starting from what you show us?

Comment: Thank you, I understand all of those but my problem is that I want to create an array made up of multiple different ranges.  I want to add range1 to myarray then I want to add range2 (without deleting range1) to myarray...then range3 and range4 etc.  The end result will be an array with values from 4 different ranges in it.  Is that possible?

Comment: So step 1 would be myarray = range1.  Then how do I add range2 to myarray without overwriting range1?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But only if all arrays have the same number of columns... If this is your need, it should be so simple to delete everything from your question, present two, three existing arrays, mentioning that they have the same number of columns and asking for joining them, in terms of rows... In such a circumstance, I (or somebody else) will post an answer containing a function able to do that... If I will post  now the answer, somebody not reading our comments will think that I have an understanding problem, I am afraid... If you need to join their columns, it can be done, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233174/discussion-between-exoticdisease-and-faneduru).

Comment: Now, I can see that you updated the question to ask for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to join two arrays in terms of columns, please use the next function:

```
Function JoinArrCol(arr As Variant, ar1 As Variant) As Variant
     Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastItem As Long
     
     lastItem = UBound(arr, 2)
     ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2) + UBound(ar1, 2))
     
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ar1, 2)
            arr(i, j + lastItem) = ar1(i, j)
        Next j
     Next i
     JoinArrCol = arr
 End Function
```

In order to place the ranges in arrays, please use the next `Sub`, which uses the above function to join the arrays. The joining result will be dropped in the next sheet:

```
Sub joinArraysPerColumns()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arrFin
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set sh1 = sh.Next
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    arr1 = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).value
    arr2 = sh.Range("C2:E" & lastR).value
    
    arrFin = JoinArrCol(arr1, arr2)
    sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!  This looks like I can use it, I'll have a play and see how it goes!

Comment: @exoticdisease: Glad I (finally) could help! You may use your named ranges instead of `"A2:B" & lastR`, or even putting all names in an array and use them from there. There are only two arrays necessary. The one receiving the named range value and another one which will all the time be incrementing, joining it with the new array extract from the range. You firstly must use `If not IsArray(arrFin) then ArrFin = arr`. Where `arrFin` should be the array joining everything and `arr` the array taking the values from each named range... If itlooks problematic, do  not hesitate to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Not much code to loop through the named ranges

```vb
Sub CopyRanges()

    Dim wsDashData As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngDest As Range, c As Integer
    Dim namerange, data, i As Integer
    namerange = Array("timelinemarket", "clientdetailsmarket", "premisesmonthlymarket", "cashinflowmarket", "cashoutflowmarket")
    
    Set wsDashData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rngDest = Sheet2.Range("A1")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(namerange)
        data = wsDashData.Range(namerange(i)).Value2
        c = UBound(data, 2)
        rngDest.Resize(UBound(data), c).Value2 = data
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, c)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a play with this code - your solution of putting the named ranges into an array looks really promising.